# How can I draw this polyhedron?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, polyhedra

I'm high school student, and I am doing research about buildings using *Mathematica*. I want to plot the polyhedron shown below:

[image: the desired polyhedron]

I have tried using `Table`, but it doesn't work. Please help me.

```
v = Table[
   {
    {-2, -2, h}
    , {-2, 2, h}
    , {2, 2, h}
    , {2, -2, h}
    , {-3, -3, h + 3}
    , {-3, 3, h + 3}
    , {3, 3, h + 3}
    , {3, -3, h + 3}
    }
   , {h, 0, 1, 3}
   ];
i = {
   {1, 2, 3, 4}
   , {1, 2, 6, 5}
   , {2, 3, 7, 6}
   , {3, 4, 8, 7}
   , {4, 1, 5, 8}
   , {5, 6, 7, 8}
   };

Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[v, Polygon[i]], Axes -> True]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Could you be more specific in your question? . Only [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) are likely to get great answers. Please [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to [improve it](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and make more clear what you are asking. Also consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Aren't you doing exactly that?

Comment: Can you clarify what you need, because you are using a `Table`, do you just want help to simplifiy your code?

Comment: sorry. I want to regulate height using table

Comment: In case this was contributing to your confusion, please note that the iteration specifier `{h, 0, 1, 3}` makes `h` run from 0 to 1 in steps of 3. So in fact `h` only ever takes the value 0. To run from 0 to 3 in steps of 1, use `{h, 0, 3, 1}` or just `{h, 0, 3}`. (The final value and step are given in the opposite order compared to, e.g., Matlab.)

Comment: @유민우 If my answer below is acceptable to you and solves your problem, please consider accepting it formally by clicking on the grey triangle next to the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am glad that you are using *Mathematica* in your high school project.

I think you forgot to mention in your question that the code you posted doesn't actually produce the image you showed; you may also want to mention where you obtained that image.

Anyway, since your figure is made up of repeating units, I generated one unit, then translated it multiple times to generate the rest of the figure. You could use the following code as an inspiration to tweak to your desires:

```
Graphics3D[
  Table[
    GeometricTransformation[
      Pyramid[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {1, 1, -2}}],
      TranslationTransform[{0, 0, n}]
    ],
    {n, 0, 5, 1}
  ],
  Axes -> True
]
```

[image: pyramids]

---

### UPDATE

As @J.M. mentioned in his comment, this is a pretty versatile approach. You can swap out different 3D repeating units, and the rest of the code will do the stacking for you.

In fact, a more faithful representation of what you showed in the picture can be obtained using a [pyramidal frustum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PyramidalFrustum.html) (i.e. a pyramid with the tip chopped off) as the repeating unit:

```
repeatingUnit = Hexahedron[{
    (*bottom face*)
    {-2, -2, 0}, {2, -2, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {-2, 2, 0},
    (*top face*)
    {-3, -3, 3}, {3, -3, 3}, {3, 3, 3}, {-3, 3, 3}
    }];

Graphics3D[
  Table[
    GeometricTransformation[
      repeatingUnit,
      TranslationTransform[{0, 0, n}]
    ],
    {n, 0, 15, 3}
  ],
  Axes -> True
]
```

[image: frusta]

You can explore further by considering e.g. less regular pyramids, pyramids with non-horizontal bases, etc.

Comment: Hopefully, OP realizes that the `Pyramid[]` in your code is replaceable, if, say, he wants frustums instead.

Comment: @J. M. Good point. I updated the code to include that, in specific to separate the construction of an explicit repeating unit from the generation of the 3D graphic itself.

Comment: +1 for the effort put into interpreting a weird question